# Read data from file in two separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file

I'm new to python and am trying to load data from a file.
My file looks like this:

```
TION 13168375
NTHE 11234972
THER 10218035
THAT 8980536
OFTH 8132597
FTHE 8100836
THES 7717675
WITH 7627991
```

I want to extract both columns into separate arrays.
What I tried so far is:

```
import numpy as np
s=open("Equadgrams.txt", "r")
data = np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('mystring','S4'),('myint','i8')])
```

In the documentation of the loadtxt command it looked like I can split the result into separate arrays, but this gave me errors.

```
x,y = np.loadtxt(s, dtype=[('mystring','S4'),('myint','i8')])

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

One additional thing that I noticed:
The integers in the data array seem to be alright, but the strings are not read as intended.
I get for the first entry: b'TION' which is of type class<class 'numpy.bytes_'>

I hope that someone is so kind to help me with my problem.

Comment: In `genfromtxt` use `U4' instead of 'S4' (default unicode versus bytestring).  `data['mystring']` and `data['myint']` should give you the desired arrays.

Comment: The `loadtxt` should give a 1d, 2 field array just like `genfromtxt`.  Obviously you can't `unpack` that, on the first large dimension, into 2 variables.  `loadtxt` has an 'unpack' parameter, but I'm not sure it will work with the structured dtype (it just 'transposes' the output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `pandas`, it's a well know `python` library to deal with tabular data like the one you have.
So first install `pandas` using `pip` as follows:

```
pip install pandas
```

Then load your file like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Equadgrams.txt",sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want two different arrays you can use the following:

```py
s = open("filename.txt", "r")
lines = s.readlines()

strings = [line.split[' '][0] for line in lines]
ints = [line.split[' '][1] for line in lines]

s.close()
```

I hope that's the correct form you want it in. Otherwise you have to convert it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through every line in the file and append the values to x and y using the .split method:

```
x = []
y = []
file = open("file.txt","r")
for line in file:
    x.append(line.split(" ")[0])
    y.append(line.split(" ")[1])
```